# Need for a uiview but I have only a var of type some view

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview

I have a variable "meme" which contains an image and two textfields :

```
var meme: some View {
        image!
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
            .overlay(
                TextField("TOP", text: $topText)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 30))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.75)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.vertical, 50.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        topText = ""
                    },
                alignment: .top
            )
            .overlay(
                TextField("BOTTOM", text: $bottomText)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 30))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.75)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.vertical, 50.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        bottomText = ""
                    },
                alignment: .bottom
            )
    }
```

I want to create an image with all my image and two text given by the textFields. To do so, I used the draw method from UIGraphics. Moreover, I am just a beginner in swiftui. I found a code in internet where the person implemented a function to create an image from a uiview :

```
func createImage(from view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), true, 1)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let generatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return generatedImage!
    }
```

But in my case, I have a variable with a some view type. I tried to create a new struct as a view. But it remains a view, how can I create a UIView ?

Edit : I tried what Raja Kishan proposed by writing :

```
items.append(createImage(from: UIHostingController(rootView: meme).view))
```

in a button's action part.

But the following line throws an error saying that "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" :

```
view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

in the createImage function.

Why is it nil ?

Comment: You can get view by this ```UIHostingController(rootView: yourSwiftUIView).view```

Comment: I have a problem : it is returning a nil value.

Comment: You have to make another struct view for meme var ane have to pass struct view instead of var view.

Comment: It throws the same error at the same line !

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWIFTUI Image

```
Image(uiImage: createImage(from YOURVIEW))
```